# Android/Java: Html scraping, regex album art from Spotify

Tags: java, android, html, regex, web-scraping

I'm working on a project that requires me to scrape an image link to an album art from open.spotify

Example: http://open.spotify.com/track/296mPMQavmf1vvxYrUvLN8

In this example I'm looking for this tag: `<img id="cover-art" src="http://o.scdn.co/image/ff3874d40abf6e6e7763e39bdb2003cf503cba10">`

As output from the regex I would like this: `http://o.scdn.co/image/ff3874d40abf6e6e7763e39bdb2003cf503cba10`

I have been trying to get this to work for some time but my solutions always happen in more than 2-3 steps. I'm still learning regex and can't get my head around how to solve this.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Use a html parser like `htmlcleaner` or `JSoup` it will simplify your work. You can use xpath expressions here. I think regex should do the work `"img\s+id=\"cover-art\"\s+src=\"(.*?)\""`.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you shouldn't be using regexps to parse HTML. Try using [JSoup](http://www.jsoup.org) instead - it's a bit more practical.

Go fetch the jsoup JAR, add it to your project and do something like this:

```
class SpotifyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            // CSS-style selectors are your new best friend when scraping!
            Elements coverArts = doc.select("img[id=cover-art]");
            for (Element coverArt : coverArts) {
                String url = coverArt.absUrl("src");
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
                    res.add(url);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error processing document", e);
        }
        return res;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Do something with your links: " + result);
    }
}
```

Start it like this in your activity:

```
new SpotifyTask().execute("http://open.spotify.com/track/296mPMQavmf1vvxYrUvLN8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the complete page into a string, then this regex should do the trick:

```
id="cover-art" src="([^"]+?)"
```

It anchors to the 'id="cover-art" src="' and read everything until the next '"' as match 1. This should give you only the URL for the image.

Depending on your preferred matching choice, you might give necessary anchor tags along, like this:

```
^.*id="cover-art" src="([^"]+?)".*$
```

This is necessary, as some matching classes in Java always want to match the whole string, which the first regex wouldn't do.